# Data from local storage modified when passing to php

Tags: javascript, php, json, local-storage

I'm trying to write a form that on first submition writes form fields to local storage. I have a button that reads the data back from local storage. I want to pass this data to php so it can then be posted back into the form.

The data is json encoded, when I try and pass the data to php it is being corrupted and not recognised as json encoded.

I'm sending to local storage:

```
$encodedString= json_encode( array());

<script type="text/javascript">
  // Access the elements of the array
  var passed_array =[];
  var passed_array = ('<?= $encodedString; ?>');
  localStorage.setItem('<?= $hostname; ?>',JSON.stringify(passed_array));
</script>
```

To retrieve from local storage:

```
<script>
    var starray = localStorage.getItem('<?= $hostname; ?>');
    //document.write(starray);
</script>
```

if I output starray from inside the script using

```
document.write(starray);
```

It is valid json data and can be decoded, I'm feeding the output into:
https://json_decode.onlinephpfunctions.com/ to test.

When I try and pass the json data into a php so I can "json_decode" it, it is being corrupted and not seen as valid json format.
I'm passing to php using:

```
$starray = "<script>JSON.parse(document.write(starray));</script>";
```

The output from `document.write(starray);` is valid json:

```
{"hostname":"aaaa","loopback_ip":"10.255.69.83","upstream_device":"","aapr_int_ip":"","aapr_bundle":"","aapr_int":"","linkid_west":"","aapr_exchange_west":"","ring_id":"","be_ip":"10.255.104.217","uplink_bundle":"10","phy_int":"","ospf_area":"","oob_ip":"","exchangename":"","siteaddress":"","city":"","state":null,"floor":"","suite":"","rack":"","user_id":""}
```

The output from `$starray = "<script>JSON.parse(document.write(starray));</script>";` is NOT valid json:

```
string(53) "{"hostname":"aaaa","loopback_ip":"10.255.69.83","upstream_device":"","aapr_int_ip":"","aapr_bundle":"","aapr_int":"","linkid_west":"","aapr_exchange_west":"","ring_id":"","be_ip":"10.255.104.217","uplink_bundle":"10","phy_int":"","ospf_area":"","oob_ip":"","exchangename":"","siteaddress":"","city":"","state":null,"floor":"","suite":"","rack":"","user_id":""}"
```

I can't figure out why it's being changed and how to fix it.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `var passed_array = ('<?= $encodedString; ?>');` puts a string of JSON into `passed_array`, so there's no need to stringify it again when you store it in localstorage. JSON.stringify turns objects into JSON text. JSON.parse turns JSON text into an object.

Comment: Also this: `JSON.parse(document.write(starray));`, what is that supposed to do? Why are you parsing the return value of document.write(), which is `undefined`? Assuming that you've stored the JSON string properly, you should do `dataObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(...));`. And passing that to PHP is a different matter entirely, but I suspect that's not what you're actually trying to do. To pass browser data to PHP, you need to make a request. You cannot run PHP code *after* JS code without one.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've been struggling to understand where the string is getting changed. I'm pretty sure the string is stored and retrieved properly. After retrieval th output of "document.write(starray);" is properly json_decoded. 
I don't fully understand "To pass browser data to PHP, you need to make a request".
when I do a vardump of  $starray after $starray = "<script>JSON.parse(document.write(starray));</script>";
The string data is there, just not in json format anymore.

Comment: JSON is valid JS syntax. Which means you can do `var passed_array = <?= $encodedString; ?>;` instead (note that I'm not using any quotes), and `passed_array` will be an actual object. Now you do indeed need to JSON.stringify it first though when saving it to local storage. As for passing things to PHP: all PHP code runs on the server; the resulting HTML/JS is then sent to the browser. That is when your `<script>` code runs, in the browser. You seem to think that PHP and JS run in parallel, in the order they are written in the .php file, but that is not what's happening at all.